# Android Facebook SDK Key Hash

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I successfully generated my hash key using the Facebook SDK method and set it in the facebook developer settings website. When I run the sample apps on my Nexus 5, they claim "Invalid android_key parameter. The key "EXAMPLEKEY" does not match any allowed key. Configure your app key hashes at the developers.facebook.com/apps/etc

The key that it gives me in the error is the exact key that I submitted to facebook.

I tried a method I found on stack overflow where I added code in my onCreate method in a test app on my phone, and it gave me the same key as a result.

Now I'm not sure what to do. It seems like a ton of people have had problems with the hash key, but most of them were about generating the key.

Is my key invalid or is something else wrong?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

I used multiple methods of generating the hash key and they were all the same. I was lucky to see a comment on another stack overflow question which pointed out my painfully simple problem. On the facebook developer page where you save your hash key, **you must press enter after pasting the hash key or it will say that you 'saved' it, but in fact it didn't.**

Comment: are you generating Hash key with your device or emulator?

Comment: Initially I generated the hash key with the command prompt on my PC, and then the second method I tried, I generated it with my device(Nexus 5).

Comment: try with emulator, I solved my problem in this way

Comment: Ok, can you please briefly explain your method of generating the hash key on the emulator? Did you use a code in onCreate like I mentioned or was it a different method? Thanks a lot

Comment: used code as you did..

Comment: I did the same thing with the emulator and returned the same hash key. This leads me to believe that the hash key is correct, but doesn't seem to be working correctly...